# pivot_wider() producing NA for previously full data

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I wonder why when I try to turn my data.frame into `wide` format, the two columns `Y1` & `Y2` contain `NA`?

The dataset originally had no `NA` on its `Y1` and `Y2`. Is there a fix?

```
library(tidyverse)

dat <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/v/main/mvmm.csv")

pivot_wider(dat, names_from= DV, values_from = Response)

#   School Student Treat Gender Pretest MeanPretest   TXG Index1    D1    D2 TreatCAT Gendercat    Y1    Y2
#    <int>   <int> <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>       <dbl> <dbl>  <int> <int> <int>    <int>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1      1       1  -0.5   -0.5    48.3        45.6  0.25      1     1     0        0      -0.5  29.4  NA  
# 2      1       1  -0.5   -0.5    48.3        45.6  0.25      2     0     1        0      -0.5  NA    47.4
# 3      1       2  -0.5    0.5    52.1        45.6 -0.25      1     1     0        0       0.5  52.2  NA
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have duplicated columns, If you change your code like this, it should work, The columns DV, D2, D1, Index1 contains either similar pattern or exact contrast pattern, they should be reshaped together, otherwise, rows are getting duplicated while it is being translated to wider form.We can check that by taking dim of your original table: 1600 rows, if widen properly it should have lower number of records, with below code, its converted to 800. With the OP code it was still at 1600.

```
library(tidyverse)
dat %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from= c(DV,D2,D1,Index1), values_from = Response)
```

**Output:**

```
  School Student Treat Gender     Pretest MeanPretest   TXG TreatCAT
1      1       1  -0.5   -0.5 48.34437943 45.62666702  0.25        0
2      1       2  -0.5    0.5 52.14841080 45.62666702 -0.25        0
3      1       3  -0.5   -0.5 40.56079483 45.62666702  0.25        0
4      1       4  -0.5    0.5 63.11892700 45.62666702 -0.25        0
5      1       5  -0.5   -0.5 66.79794312 45.62666702  0.25        0
6      1       6  -0.5    0.5 19.42481995 45.62666702 -0.25        0
  Gendercat    Y1_0_1_1    Y2_1_0_2
1      -0.5 29.36377525 47.35104752
2       0.5 52.20915985 49.77211761
3      -0.5 42.21330261 36.21236038
4       0.5 46.69318008 63.72433472
5      -0.5 48.70760345 48.04736328
6       0.5 23.40506554 11.07947922
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```r
dat %>%
    select(-c(Index1, D1, D2)) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = DV, values_from = Response)
```

This is happening because `Index1`, `D1`, and `D2` are all the same, and also correspond to the column you want to pivot by. If you get rid of them it works fine